# Changing Apple developer company/organization name

Tags: app-store

Say an independent US-based developer creates an Apple Developer account as an individual contributor. They choose a company/organization name "XYZ Apps". They never create an LLP or file any type of business paperwork other than reporting taxes.

Now the developer wishes to change the company/organization name. Apple requests "court/business" documentation verifying the new name. The developer doesn't have said docs because there hasn't been any official business name change or anything.

**How can the independent developer update their company/organization name in this case?**

Perhaps they can tell Apple it's just an aesthetic name change. Any feedback from people with experience is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: after reading around the web it seems like creating another developer account might be the easiest route. This assumes you don't have apps with the original account where the exact name is important.

Comment: What's a more relevant stack exchange to post this on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple does not appear to allow any "aesthetic" name changes, only a legal incorporation name or a legal corporate name change.  So you may need to incorporate your business, and request Apple change your developer enrollment to a company enrollment, in order to change the name on your developer account.